# How to setup webpack.config to use jsx-html-class in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I've already installed `jsx-html-class` package via `npm` but i'm not sure how to modify my webpack.config.js file to make use of it.

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
    entry: "./js/index.js",
    module: { 
        loaders: [
            {
                test:/\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: "node_modules",
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                            presets:["react", "es2015", "stage-0"],
                            plugins:["transform-decorators-legacy", "jsx-html-class"]
                }
            }
     ]
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/src/",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    }
};
```

Comment: Don't you mean `jsx-html-class` ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsx-html-class . also.. do you *really really* need this? Just write `className`

Comment: my bad, i did mean `jsx-html-class` and that is actually the package i downloaded. I don't absolutely need it but would prefer to have it for easier readability and now i just wanna know how just for the sake of knowing.

Comment: What is the error you get when you try to run webpack?

Comment: If i inclue `jsx-html-class` in my `plugins` i get the error: `Module build failed: TypeError: babel.Transformer is not a contstructor at module.exports (C:\Users\owner\Desktop\Reduxstagram\node_modules\jsx-html-class\index.js:2:10` if i remove `jsx-html-class` from the `plugins` i get the error: `Warning: Unknown DOM property class. Did you mean className?` or

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the same problem with this:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-react-html-attrs
```

then add this to your webpack config:

```
loaders: [{
    test: /\.js?$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
        plugins: ['react-html-attrs']
    }
}]
```

or via .babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "react-html-attrs"
  ]
}
```